# $H$ and $K$ are supposed to be closed in $X$, Why?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a closed subspace of $X$. Let $H$ and $K$ be closed in $A$. Now $H$ and $K$ are supposed to be closed in $X$, Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of $H$ in $A$ is open in $A$, so is the intersection of some open set $U$ in $X$ with $A$. The complement of $H$ in $X$ is then the union of $U$ and the complement of $A$ in $X$, both of which are open.

Exactly the same argument works for $K$ - there seems to be no reason to state the problem with two subsets, so I assume this comes from some larger context.

Answer (score 0):

If A is closed in X then X\A must be open in X.
If H (or K) is is closed in A then A\H must be open in A. Hence there exists some open set B such that A\H $\subset$ B $\subset$ X and H $\not \subset$ B.
Now X\H = X\A $\cup$ B which is a union of open sets so this must be open.
Hence H is closed in X.

Comment: Note that $A\setminus H$ is only open in $A$, not necessarily in $X$; but it is the intersection of some open set in $X$ with $A$, so you can use this in the union instead.

Comment: realised this just after I added it. Fixed now.

Comment: I think that $H\not\subset B$ isn't enough either, you need $H\cap B=\varnothing$. The condition I'm used to is just that $A\cap B=A\setminus H$.

Comment: yes, you're right. Long day...